# Internet Federated web server?

Tags: internet, dns, webserver, cross-platform

I'm not sure what to call this...

What I would like to do is have a web server that is capable of serving pages from separate servers across the internet (not a local network).

eg, 
If I visit `http://www.example.com` I will be serving data from a machine in America. If I visit  `http://www.example.com/ServiceB` the machine will be serving from a machine in Brazil, just as  `http://serviceC.example.com` would call the server in Canada.

What would I need to do to achieve this? Is there a name for what I'm trying to do? Logically to me this would be called a federated web server... But I cannot find anything for that on google.

Comment: Isn't this Akamai's service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @Shiki is in the ballpark. 'proxy' or 'gateway' is where you need to search.  You are not building a federate, you're acting describing more of a gateway.

Try reading up on [apache mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html).  It may be what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just make CNAME values?  For instance, could http://www.example.com point to a North American server, and http://es.example.com could point to a South American server, and http://eu.example.com could point to a European server, etc.